# Android apps and icons

Tags: android

Coming from web development to Android development, I've found that there are many similarities and differences.

Being used to icon fonts, I have some questions about using fonts and icons in Android apps.

1. Are icon fonts a "thing" in Android app development?
2. I've seen people mentioned putting icon images under `drawable`, but others say to put them under `mipmap`. What are the differences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1.** Yes, Icon Fonts are a "thing" in Android. I suggest you do a Google Search on how to use them, or you could ask another question on StackOverflow.

**Q2.**
The `mipmap` folder should only be used for your app's **Launcher Icon**, all other images should be placed under the `drawable` folder. This is because the launcher icon's resolution is different from the device's current density. See [this for more](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)